# Maven build process - building two projects using one build script

Tags: maven, build

I am trying to figure out how to use Maven for the build process of the project I am involved in. I want something like this:

Let's say we have two or three projects with the following structure:

```
 .
   |-src
   |---main
   |-----java
   |-------com
   |---------mycompany
   |-----------app
   |---test
   |-----java
   |-------com
   |---------mycompany
   |-----------app
```

Building this project will be easy using a pom.xml file. Let's say this file/folder structure are under sampleProject1 and I want to have another sample project called sampleProject2, which end up like this:

```
sampleProject1
   |-src
   |---main
   |-----java
   |-------com
   |---------mycompany
   |-----------app
   |---test
   |-----java
   |-------com
   |---------mycompany
   |-----------app
   |-target
   |---classes
   |-----com
   |-------mycompany
   |---------app
   |---maven-archiver
   |---surefire-reports
   |---test-classes
   |-----com
   |-------mycompany
   |---------app



sampleProject2
   |-src
   |---main
   |-----java
   |-------com
   |---------mycompany
   |-----------app
   |---test
   |-----java
   |-------com
   |---------mycompany
   |-----------app
   |-target
   |---classes
   |-----com
   |-------mycompany
   |---------app
   |---maven-archiver
   |---surefire-reports
   |---test-classes
   |-----com
   |-------mycompany
   |---------app
```

I can use pom.xml in the sampleProject1 and sampleProject2 to build the project. What I am looking for is to have one pom.xml file to build this two projects. I don't want to copy two projects in one folder structure and create a new sampleProject3 which have all the files.

My background is Ant, so may be I need to think different using Maven, appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a multi-module build:

```
Parent
  +--- pom.xml
  +--- project1
          +--- pom.xml
          +--- src/...
  +--- project2
          +--- pom.xml
          +--- src/...
```

Take a deeper look into the [documentation of Maven about multi-module builds](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html).